# Web scraping after clicking on two buttons

Tags: python, pandas, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape data from this website http://rgphentableaux.hcp.ma/Default1/ by clicking on the 2 radio buttons, then by choosing from a list like this  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W2c3I.png)

I need to do this for all the choices available in that list and add the tables to a dataframe I have
here is what I tried so far but it didn't work

```
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
    pip install selenium
    from selenium import webdriver
    browser=webdriver.Chrome()
    url = "http://rgphentableaux.hcp.ma/Default1/"
    browser.get(url) #navigate to the page
    browser.find_element_by_xpath(".//input[@type='radio' and 
                     @value='5']").click()
    browser.find_element_by_id("CGEO").click()
    time.sleep(3)
    browser.find_element_by_xpath(".//input[@type='button' and 
                    @value='Afficher']").click()
    tabs = browser.find_elements_by_id('IEE')
    innerHTML = browser.execute_script("return 
                 document.body.innerHTML")
    soup_level2=BeautifulSoup(innerHTML, 'html.parser')
```

Ps: I need to get the tables that are here too
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could do the whole thing with `requests` and `bs4` by mimicking the requests the page makes. You just need to loop the regions, in the right order, and add the current region number to the `'CGEO'` param in each request.

---

This:

```
soup = bs(s.get(url).content, 'lxml')
regions = [i.text.strip() for i in soup.select('#REGIONSLIST option')]
```

gathers an initial list of the region names from the landing url.

---

This:

```
for k,v in regions.items():
    params = (('type', 'Region'), ('CGEO', v), ('them', '5'))
```

sets the `CGEO` param with the `option` tag `value` attribute for the region e.g.
`Tanger-Tetouan-Al Hoceima` is `'01'`.

`Region` option is set within the `type` param.

`Langues locales utilisées` option is set within the `them` param i.e. `'5'`.

---

This:

```
for y in range(3):
    row.extend([data[i-y+2]['DATA2014']])
```

just reverses the order of items such that `Ens, Fem, Masc` in each dictionary within `data` gets added to the `row` in the desired output order of `Masc, Fem, Ens`.

---

**Py:**

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

def add_rows(region, data):
    for i in range(0, len(data)//3, 3):
        row = [region, data[i]['INDICATEUR'].split('_')[-1]]
        for y in range(3):
            row.extend([data[i-y+2]['DATA2014']])
        final.append(row)
        
url = 'http://rgphentableaux.hcp.ma/Default1'    
headers= {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0',  'Referer': url}    
final = []

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers = headers
    soup = bs(s.get(url).content, 'lxml')
    regions = {i.text.strip():i['value'].strip() for i in soup.select('#REGIONSLIST option')}
    
    for k,v in regions.items():
        params = (('type', 'Region'), ('CGEO', v), ('them', '5'))
        r = s.get(f'{url}/getDATA/', params=params)
        data = r.json()
        add_rows(k, data)
    
df = pd.DataFrame(final, columns = ['Region', 'Lang', 'Masc', 'Fem', 'Ens'])
print(df)
```

---

**EDIT:**

To get all 3 tables (ensemble, urbain, rural) adjust the custom function as shown below and add in the additional loop `for n in range(0, len(data), block)`:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

def add_rows(table, region, data_block):
    for i in range(0, len(data_block), 3):
        row = [table, region, data_block[i]['INDICATEUR'].split('_')[-1]]
        for y in range(3):
            row.extend([data_block[i-y+2]['DATA2014']])
        final.append(row)
        
url = 'http://rgphentableaux.hcp.ma/Default1'    
headers= {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0',  'Referer': url}
tables = ['ens', 'urb', 'rur']
final = []

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers = headers
    soup = bs(s.get(url).content, 'lxml')
    regions = {i.text.strip():i['value'].strip() for i in soup.select('#REGIONSLIST option')}
    
    for k,v in regions.items():
        params = (('type', 'Region'), ('CGEO', v), ('them', '5'))
        r = s.get(f'{url}/getDATA/', params=params)
        data = r.json()
        block = len(data)//3
        
        for n in range(0, len(data), block):
            table = tables[n//block]
            add_rows(table, k, data[n:n+block])
            
df = pd.DataFrame(final, columns = ['Table', 'Region', 'Language', 'Masc', 'Fem', 'Ens'])
print(df)
```

Comment: Thank you so much it works, you're a lifesaver.

Comment: sorry to bother you, but how can I get the other tables the ones in 'Urbain' and 'Rural' and not just the ones in 'Ensemble'. Thank you

Comment: You mean _Communes et centres urbains_  as well as _Provinces_?

Comment: No, I mean right above the table that appears there are three choices 'Ensemble', 'Urbain' and 'Rural' i need to get the tables that are there too and not just the one in 'Ensemble' I hope it's clear.

Comment: I edited the post and added an image so you could see it

Comment: Ah.... yes, those values are all present in `data` . The function `add_rows` needs to be altered to write out all three tables each time rather than just `ens` from `data`.

Comment: I have updated answer for you. See edit at bottom/

Comment: thank you, thank you so so much you really are a lifesaver, I am a newbie to programming and hope that one day I can be as good as you

Answer (score 0):

To select the item with text as **Langues locales utilisées** and **Region** and scrape the table you can use the following solution:

```
driver.get("http://rgphentableaux.hcp.ma/Default1/")
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@text='Langues locales utilisées']"))).click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@value='Region']").click()
driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@value='Choisir une entitée']"))))
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@value='Choisir une entitée']"))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//li[contains(., 'Tanger-Tetouan-Al Hoceima')]"))).click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@value='Afficher']").click()
print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//table[@class='tableau']/tbody"))).text)
```

Console Output:

```
Population municipale 16 747 522 16 862 562 33 610 084
Répartition selon les grands groupes d'âges
Moins de 6 ans 12.4 11.8 12.1
De 6 à 14 ans 16.5 15.7 16.1
De 15 à 59 ans 61.8 63.0 62.4
60 ans et plus 9.3 9.5 9.4
Répartition selon le groupe d'âges quinquennal
0-4 ans 10.4 9.9 10.2
5-9 ans 9.2 8.8 9.0
10-14 ans 9.3 8.8 9.0
15-19 ans 8.9 8.8 8.9
20-24 ans 9.0 9.1 9.1
25-29 ans 8.2 8.4 8.3
30-34 ans 7.7 8.0 7.8
35-39 ans 6.8 7.2 7.0
40-44 ans 6.3 6.5 6.4
45-49 ans 5.3 5.6 5.4
50-54 ans 5.3 5.4 5.3
55-59 ans 4.2 4.0 4.1
60-64 ans 3.4 3.3 3.4
65-69 ans 1.9 1.9 1.9
70-74 ans 1.6 1.8 1.7
75 ans et plus 2.4 2.6 2.5
État matrimonial
Célibataire 57.9 48.4 53.2
Marié 40.8 42.0 41.4
Divorcé 0.7 2.4 1.6
Veuf 0.6 7.1 3.9
Âge moyen au premier mariage 31.3 25.7 28.5
Fécondité
Parité moyenne à 45-49 ans / 3.5 /
Indice synthétique de fécondité / 2.2 /
```